# What files do i need to link to my xcode project (built in gamemaker) to make it work?

Tags: xcode, game-maker-studio-2

I have seen similar issues on here which has led me to believe i need to link binary files with library. However, i cannot figure out which ones i need, can any one help me with this ? I have macOS catalina 10.15.3, xcode 10.3, gamemaker 2.2.5.481 and runtime v2.2.5.378

here is my error message: 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___isPlatformVersionAtLeast", referenced from:
      UpdateIOSControllers() in libyoyo_interpreted.a(IOSGamepad.o)
      _SetHomeIndicatorDeferOption in libyoyo_interpreted.a(RunnerViewController.o)
      -[RunnerViewController viewDidLoad] in libyoyo_interpreted.a(RunnerViewController.o)
      Achievement_TeamPlayerID() in libyoyo_interpreted.a(YoYo_GameCenter.o)
      Achievement_GamePlayerID() in libyoyo_interpreted.a(YoYo_GameCenter.o)
      PB_Challenges(HTTP_REQ_CONTEXT*, void*, int*) in libyoyo_interpreted.a(YoYo_GameCenter.o)
      PB_PlayerPic(HTTP_REQ_CONTEXT*, void*, int*) in libyoyo_interpreted.a(YoYo_GameCenter.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score -1):

Bluetooth gamepad support is added in iOS 13, which requires XCode 11 to work; you probably only need to upgrade xcode.

Reference:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/123003